# Wordpress get woocommerce categories as array

Tags: wordpress

I need to have all my categories in an array to auto add products to categories but I failed :/ I have this code:

```
function getCats($catlist, $name) {

        $regex = '('.implode('|', $catlist).')';
        $success = preg_match_all($regex, $name, $matches);
        return $success ? $matches[0] : [];   

}
```

in other function:

```
        $catlist = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        ) );            


        $firstCat = getCats($catlist, $name)[0];
```

but if I run the code I get this message:

An object of class `WP_Term` could not be converted to string in

anyone know how I can handle it to save all categories in a string?

Comment: Where you are getting product categories, it returns object. Thus $catlist is an object. Your "getCats()" function is written to process text. You will have to change it to process object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked `get_terms()` function returns an error:

> WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array (
>   [0] => Invalid taxonomy. ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )

```
$catlist = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        ) );
```

That's why it gives an error:

> An object of class WP_Term could not be converted to a string

**Note:** Please solve `Invalid taxonomy` error first by using https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13480/get-terms-return-errors then it will solve automatically.